# Framework Bolts not Found resulting in Linker Command Failed with Exit

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to install the Facebook SDK using Cocaopod. I managed to install fine.

This is what is inside the Podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Login-FB' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Login-FB

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

end
```

However, after installation, when I run Build in the App, I get the error shown below:

```
ld: framework not found Bolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems like my Pod files are not really pulling the framework down from its source. I am not sure why. Because I think this Pod install command should create a folder called Framework and it should have the Frameworks readily available, but it is not so in my case.

Comment: did you `pod install` ?

Comment: Yep I did do pod install

Comment: Try build clean and re-building

Comment: Yeah, I have also tried that